# Osculating circle given parametric coordinates in polar form

Tags: differential-geometry, polar-coordinates, curves, parametric

I have the following parametric equation for a curve in polar form:
\begin{align}
r(t) &= r_0-kt\\
\phi(t)&=h\ln(r_0-k_0t)+a
\end{align}
where $(r_0,h,a,k_0,k)\in\mathbb{R}$
what is the radius of the osculating circle $R(t)$?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide additional context. What is the relevance of this problem to you/us? What methods have you tried so far?

Comment: This is a trajectory of a drone guided by a laser spot sensor. I applied the method of differential geometry, but the result I obtained is not very convincing.

Comment: **HINT:** $r(\theta)=e^{(\theta-a)/h}$. Here is a [plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0ovfwwmfrb) to help visualize.

Comment: @K.defaoite: In the first equation there is $k$. In the second, $k_0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Frenet- Serret relations with vectors $(N,T)$ in normal plane in the usual differential form ***after converting***  from polar to rectangular coordinates.

```
rz = 0.75; kz = 0.4; k = 0.25; h = 0.2; a = 1.25;
rho[t_] = (rz - k t); th[t_] = h Log[rz - kz t] + a ;
ParametricPlot[rho[t] {Cos[th[t]], Sin[th[t]]}, {t, -5, 2}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1.25]
```

In the above  *Mathematica* used function definition f[t_].

[image]

Comment: $k$ is not necessarily $k_0$ as OP emphasized in the comment.

Comment: I was giving him a hint.. changed it now..

Answer (score -1):

[image: Mathematica]

This is the Mathematica output, using the parameter names given.

Let me elaborate it a bit. I just started with $r'$ and $\phi'$, then rotated the vector $(r',r \phi')$ by an angle of $\phi$ to put them in XY coordinates. The norm of the derivative of the normalized resulting vector is the curvature, i.e., the inverse of the radius.